# How can I transfer large remote files to google cloud storage?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm working on a project where I need to extract large sets of data from a remote plateform, into google cloud storage. This plateform is providing HTTPS download links via a specific API.
Downloading files locally, then uplodading files to GC is an option I can't use.

I've been using app engine to generate needed download links, and transfer these files into google cloud storage (using basic PHP file_get_contents/fwrite).
Working fine for small files (approx 20MB), only writting an empty file for larger ones.

Answer (score 1):

So step 1, make sure your code is being run via a task queue, cron job, or via the deferred library otherwise if running as a normal request it will timeout in about 30 seconds.

On App Engine, the [URLFetch API underlies the `file_get_contents` methods](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/issue-requests) and is subject to URL Fetch's timeouts, which is pretty short I believe (10 seconds?). You can [specify a timeout](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/issue-requests#setting_a_request_timeout) parameter, which should be able to increase it somewhat, but that still might not be sufficient for you. Might be something like this:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array('http'=>
    array(
        'timeout' => 1200,  // 20 minutes
    )
));

echo file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/', false, $context);
```

If you continue running into URL Fetch's underlying constraints, you might switch to using cURL instead, which runs over the sockets API. If you're download takes longer than 10 minutes, you might need to change your App's `service` to use a basic or manual scaled instance rather than automatic. The automatic scaled instances timeout after 10 minutes. The manual and basic instances can have tasks that run up to 24 hours in length. You might create a separate "worker" service just to hold this code and keep the rest of your app in the default service.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedbacks. This in addition to upload_max_filesize, drive me up to 32MB files max. I'm guessing this is not due to timeout but some other limitation?